# Uncaught type error in javascript while using drawimage within a class in javassript

Tags: javascript, class, canvas, types

I have a problem while trying to create a class in javascript with an image as a property. The line I commented with the context.drawImage throws this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'.

I find this interesting, because when i look at the image i am passing down as a paramater while debugging, it tells me that it is a HTMLImageElement. I come from statically typed languages and i can't figure out why there is a type error when the passed object is clearly of the type requested by the error. `

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var edgeY = 600;

        function Start()
        {
            var letter = new Letter(true, 10);
        }


        function Letter(_isSyllable, speed)
        {
            this.isSyllable = _isSyllable;
            this.imgObject = new Image(80, 80);
            this.posY = 10;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.ImageReady = false;
            var source;
            if (this.isSyllable)
            {
                source = "./Maganhangzok/image_part_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 14 + 1)) + ".jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                source = "./Massalhangzok/image_part_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1)) + ".jpg";
            }
            this.imgObject.src = source;     
            this.imgObject.onLoad = new function()
            {
                this.ImageReady = true;
                console.log(this.imgObject);
                context.drawImage(this.imgObject, 120, this.posY); //this one throws the exception
            }


        }
        Letter.prototype.Move = new function ()
        {
            this.posY += this.speed;
            context.clearRect(120, this.posY, 80, 80);
            if (!this.ImageReady)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.posY + 80 > edgeY)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                context.drawImage(this.imgObject, 120, this.posY);
                return false;
            }

        }


    </script>`
```

Comment: How do you call this `onLoad` method? (JS is case sensitive and the event handler is all lower case). Your type error can be caused by an HTMLImage with no valid source loaded yet.

Comment: I tried it, but the function is called the same way without the typo, but i started stepping through the function and i noticed that in the onload's event function the this.imgObject suddenly becomes undefined, while inside the constructor it does have a value. Why does it lose it's value when the event fires?

Comment: Because event handlers are by default bound to the element on which fired the event. You would have to call this function's `bind()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first call onLoad and the set the source url.

```
    this.imgObject.onLoad = new function()
    {
        this.ImageReady = true;
        console.log(this.imgObject);
        context.drawImage(this.imgObject, 120, this.posY); //this one throws the exception
    }
    this.imgObject.src = source;
```